# Can I edit a jira issue via API without creating history?

Tags: jira

I'm tasked with tracking error incidence rates in Jira.

The problem I have is that as I increment counters a history row is created. For high-volume alerts this could easily create hundreds of thousands of history rows like this:

```
Count updated from 1 to 2
Count updated from 2 to 3
```

This is both a lot of noise on the ticket and a significant burden for Jira to handle. Is there a way I can configure jira or post the update request so that no history will be created?

This is not a matter of the email notifications, but the data on the issue itself. Creating these log records creates stability issues for Jira and it's data that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I would use different DB entity for this (AO). This would contain reference to the issue and the API would be acessible through some servlet.

Comment: So you want to update a ticket WITHOUT sending out notifications about it? With the REST API, you can't (see feature request https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34423 )

Comment: @Koshinae it's not a duplicate. I'm not interesting in stopping the emails. I'm interested in stopping the logging **on the issue itself**

Comment: So you don't want to have a new changegroup/changeitem entry generated? Well... can you directly update the `customfieldvalue` table?

Comment: @Koshinae for sure I could directly update the DB, I'm hoping to avoid this as it makes me subject to schema changes.

Comment: Well, I don't know of other ways. I hope someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the REST API, you can't, and likely won't (see [JRA-34423](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34423)) in the near future.

With the SOAP API, you technically can, if you are still on a deprecated JIRA version.

You also can through direct DB updates, but then you must take care of the Lucene cache inconsistencies, which is another question :-)